# Windows 7 64-bit driver for HP Color Laserjet CM1015 MFP

Tags: windows-7, hp-laserjet, multi-function-printer

I bought my HP Color Laserjet CM1015 MFP about 5 years ago. It worked flawlessly on Windows Vista (unsure of 32/64-bit). This worked well on Windows 7 64-bit on two different machines (I upgraded to a new machine about six months ago). Just about two months ago it started to have problems with not being discoverable always. This was after HP Software Update program downloading an upgrade.

I have uninstalled the driver and try to reinstall from the original CD. Installation process itself fails. Using the *Program Compatibility Troubleshooter* moved it further along but did not finish.

Installing with the full software solution on this [page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1846081&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=1846080&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2100) completed successfully a few times. Unfortunately, there was no support for scanning. Worse yet, I lost the ability to print in color.

The amount of time I spent on this is ridiculous:-( I have an expensive, top notch hardware printer/scanner/copier. I hate to throw it away for lack of drivers. I welcome any workarounds (such as print servers or anything else that can revive color printing).

Comment: Here is a link for a Vista 64bit driver, see if it will install in compatibility mode....http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=1846080&prodNameId=1846081&swEnvOID=2100&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ly-51851-1

Comment: You should install the drivers from infs, not using the exe.

Answer (score 3):

HP have not done a good job at making their vista driver installer work well in Windows 7/8.
But the actual drivers work fine. Install them as follows.

- Download and unzip the [400MB full software](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=1846081&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3DtaskId%253D135%257CprodNameId%253D1846081%257Cac.admitted%253D1405903681483.876444892.199480143%257CswEnvOID%253D2100%257CprodTypeId%253D18972%257CswLang%253D8%257CprodSeriesId%253D1846080%257Clang%253Den%257Ccc%253Dus%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for Windows Vista (yes, choose the Vista option even though you have windows 7/8)

If you just want to install the scan/print drivers alone without all HP's tools, I recommend icopy scan software: http://icopy.sourceforge.net/

- Plug the printer into your USB port
- Wait for windows to detect and try to install the drivers. Printer drivers may work but scan drivers will fail
- Press windows key and type "device manager" into the search.  Press enter.
- right-click the HP scan devices that show problems and select "Update Driver Software"
- select "Browse my computer for driver software"
- enter the path to the folder you unzipped above
- done. You have scan capability!

If your **really** want the HP Toolbox installed and any other software as well as the drivers:

- you will have to go through the the hp instructions already linked by someone else.
- which is basically to set all the .exe files in the archive root to run in vista compatibility mode and run setup.exe
- But for me it always hangs when asking you to plug in the USB device.
  It may be that you can get past that by telling "network" when it asks you if your device is accessed via the network or USB. But I haven't tried it.

Comment: That ftp link on hp.com is only 5MB, and judging by the name, it's a firmware update, not the "complete package." I believe the latter is named hp_CLJ_CM1015-CM1017_v32v64_Full_Solution_AMWE.exe (not sure of an ftp address for it, but that's 400+ MB).

Comment: Sorry.  Link fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts! I still wish I could get the software to work so I could configure the "Scan to" targets, but I'll settle for having working scanning.

Answer (score 1):

HP has Windows 7 64 bit drivers posted.  [HP US CM1015](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1846081&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=1846080&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063)  That may help with printing.  The app that manages scanning may need to come from the original install and may or may not work with Win 7 64bit.

You may also want to see if the print processor you are using now is somehow not correct and only allowing mono printing.  It is in Printer properties -Advanced-Print Processor.  There may be several and you might try plain WinPrint select RAW as the data type.  Have seen some HP Print Processors mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

> Worse yet, I lost the ability to print in color

Loading the postscript driver version yields color on the CM1015.

Comment: How do you load these drivers?

Answer (score 0):

First, download the “[Full software Solution](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1846081&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=1846080&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2100)” package and then follow the [installation instructions on HP's site](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=1846080&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=1846080&objectID=c02047129).

These instructions are good, except you need to modify six, not four application files! It won't install unless you also modify `CM1017eGSG.exe` and `hpbvspst.exe`.

Good luck!